# Apostrophe trouble

Tags: apostrophe

I am confused between two sentences:

> The World Cup 2015 comprises more than 25 **one-days.**

OR

> The World Cup 2015 comprises more than 25 **one-day's.**

Which sentence is correct? If both are correct, then which sentence is preferable? Why?

Thank You.

Comment: This question is a googly! +1

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about *more than one thing/person*, it does not take apostrophe.

For instance, if there are four Managing Directors, you take 'M', 'D' and that little 's' without apostrophe.

> Four **MDs**

Apostrophe suggests possession. So, if you are talking about something that belongs to those four MDs, you need apostrophe

> MDs' (Managing Directors') cars or MD's car (Managing Director's car)

Now, here it's a tricky question...but the way to write it is...

> ...more than 25 ***one-dayers***

Or, internationally, it's ...

> ...more than 25 ***ODIs*** (One Day **Internationals**)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to say this will be "**25 one-day matches**".
Using 25 one-day's is wrong way to use apostrophe. It is never used to make plurals. When using it like this, use only in case of showing ownership.

Comment: Yes, the wording is confusing, but maybe that's why the apostrophe got used. "Never" is a strong word; sometimes an apostrophe gets used simply because the phrasing is more readable with the apostrophe. As you say, technically, that breaks the rules. But there are exceptions, and conventions change over time. There's an interesting post about this over at [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not), with more discussion [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114224/plural-of-uh-oh-and-oh-no), too.